# Grails DB Migration - how to change decimal db field to have scale property of 3?

Tags: mysql, database, grails, dbmigrate

In order to change the decimal field I have in my table, I need to know how to have a DB migration code to have this change.

Currently the field is represents as (19,2) and need to changed to (19,3) with 3 floating digits after the point.

My database is MySql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In documentation of LIQUIBASE, have a attr called [modifyDataType](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html).

Try this:

```
databaseChangeLog {
    changeSet(author: 'author', id: '1234') {
        modifyDataType(columnName: 'column', newDataType: 'DECIMAL(19,3)')
    }
}
```

I think this works fine.

Comment: it works fine!
but it changes from nullable 'false' => 'true'.

I tried to add 'nullable: false' but it didn't work well.  An exception was thrown.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Before you run the script run always dbm-update-sql. It show the sql generated by your script. Your table have a default value created? Try the addDefaultValue (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_default_value.html) to set default value. If a exception occurs or in this case a wrong default value is created, you run a rollback script. See in documentation of dbmigration on right panel ROLLBACK SCRIPTS or in section Groovy CHanges.

Comment: Is there some simple solution for this case? some magic line?

Comment: How and from where can I run the dbm-update-sql script ?

Comment: Inside your project run, on terminal, dbm-update-script

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using: addNotNullConstraint -

```
changeSet(author: 'roeyg (generated)', id: '1409232538826-2') {
    addNotNullConstraint(columnDataType: 'DECIMAL(19,3)', columnName: 'value', tableName: 'period_value')
}
```